# Spring: set User as parameter in "all" controllers and controller-functions (instead of Principal)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, principal

In a simple Web Application I could retrieve a user (from session attributes) and set it as a parameter for all servlets, using a filter:

**Inside Filter:**

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    checkUser((HttpServletRequest) request);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

private void checkUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session != null) {
        request.setAttribute("user", session.getAttribute("user"));
    }
}
```

Then I could use it in my JSP files (`<c:if test="${not empty user}"> blablabla`):

```
${user.getDisplayName}
```

---

In a Spring application I have to Inject principal in every Controller function. Even in that case a Principal is not a User, so I need to use the UserService every time:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class IndexController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    IndexController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    private static final String VIEW = "index";

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    ModelAndView index(Principal principal) {
        User user = null;
        if (principal != null) {
            user = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());
        }
        return new ModelAndView(VIEW, "user", user);
    }
}
```

---

I need the user (entity class) object because it has different functions I use. E.g. `getDisplayName()` which I use for my navbar (on every page):

**User class:**

```
public String getDisplayName() {
    if (firstname == null && lastname == null) {
        return username;
    }
    if (firstname != null && lastname != null) {
        return String.format("%s %s", firstname, lastname);
    }
    if (firstname != null) {
        return firstname;
    }
    return lastname;
}
```

I cannot use this specific user-function (getDisplayName) in Spring Framework using Security tag library functions:

```
<security:authentication property="name"/> <%-- So, this is not what I am looking for --%>
```

---

Ok, I even tried to make a custom interceptor and register it (what I don't want to do, because I have to read my user every time from database again). But then I have problems with Autowiring the UserService inside an interceptor.

What's the best way to solve this problem? Is it possible to find the User from database (findByUsername) once after a successful login, then put it in a session, then make some kind of interceptor that can do the same I did with filters before or retrieve user every time from database for every page but avoid this devious repeting code?

Answer (score 2):

You can either provide a login success handler like

```
http.formLogin().successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest arg0,
                    HttpServletResponse arg1, Authentication arg2) throws IOException,
                    ServletException {
                // here you can put your logic to save User object into session then forward/redirect to where ever you want

            }
        })
```

Or alternatively you can forward a login success to some end point like

```
http.formLogin().successForwardUrl("/loginsuccess")
```

and provide endpont implementation like

```
@RequestMapping({ "/loginsuccess" })
    public ResponseEntity<?> loginSuccess(Principal user) {

        // here you can put your logic to save User object into session then forward/redirect to where ever you want

        return "";
    }
```

Choose whichever way you find more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved:**

I made a custom interceptor, injected an autowired User Service into it, and registered that custom interceptor. It works!

```
public class MyWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public UsernameInjectionInterceptor usernameInjectionInterceptor() {
        return new UsernameInjectionInterceptor();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(usernameInjectionInterceptor());
    }
}
```

---

```
public class UsernameInjectionInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
        if (principal != null) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            if (session != null) {
                String displayName = (String) session.getAttribute("displayName");
                if (displayName == null) {
                    User user = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());
                    if (user != null) {
                        displayName = user.getDisplayName();
                        session.setAttribute("displayName", displayName);
                    }
                }
                modelAndView.addObject("displayName", displayName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```